# Powershell: Count files recursively while ignoring specific directories

Tags: powershell, recursion, count, directory

I'm currently trying to set up alerts for when certain folders have over 50 files in them. The folder directory is this:

`C:\Application\CustomerID\oneDirectory\RegisterName\transactions\FilesToCount`

For `oneDirectory`, there are multiple that I don't care about - I just care about `oneDirectory`. There are also multiple `RegisterNames` which I do care about. For `transactions`, there are multiple other directories which I don't care about. For `CustomerID`, there are multiple other directories that I do care about (customers)

Basically, I need to count the number of files in the `transactions` folder for every register for every customer, while ignoring all of the other folders. If there are over 50 or so files for any one customer, I need to get an e-mail telling me. I also need to ignore `.ini` files.

Now, I have the following script that works correctly and does the functionality needed from above but it takes way too long to run and I can't figure out why:

```
$mainFolder = "C:\Application\Customer."
$tenantID = "CustomerID"
$maxTenantID = "HighestCustomerID"
$registerPath = "\oneDirectory\"

while($tenantID -le $maxTenantID) {

    $loc = $mainFolder + $tenantID + $registerPath

    $ignore = @("failed_transactions", "saved_transactions", "temp", "offline_logs", "pos_logs", "pos_reports")

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $loc -Recurse  -Exclude *.ini | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % {

        $relative = $_.FullName.Replace($loc, "")
        $nomatch = $true

        foreach ($folder in $ignore) {
            if($relative -like "*\$folder\*") {
                $nomatch = $false
            }
        }

        if ($nomatch) { $_ }
    }

    $currentCount = $files.Count    
    if($currentCount -gt 50) {
        Send-MailMessage -From "email@whatever.com" -To "email@whatever.com" -SmtpServer "smtp.whatever.com" -Subject "Transactions stuck" -Body "$loc has over 50 transactions."
    }

    $tenantID++
}
```

As mentioned, the above code is doing the job correctly but I'm trying to set up a scheduled task to run this every hour. During testing, this takes well over an hour to complete. I've even separated it out into three scripts, each doing 1/3 of the customer list and it still takes forever.

I'm not sure if the logic behind it is the problem, or if it's just not efficient enough. This is my first powershell script so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hi, how many files are there in the biggest oneDirectory folder (roughly) ?

Comment: oneDirectory lists all of the registers (directories) per customer. So I'd say they all have less than 100 directories. The weird thing is when I run the script, sometimes it goes really slow even when there is only one register in "oneDirectory"

Comment: Aren't scheduled tasks fun?  I think the minimum time for a break on scheduled tasks is 1 hour.  I'm sorry for the confusion, but what do you expect as a result?  Is there a set of files you can specify (e.g. .txt files)?  This seems like a reporting script.  What would you like the report to show?

Answer (score 0):

If it really is your first PS script, it's a very good first shot :).

*Tip : each time you nest a loop in another, you should indent it with tab. You can also leave the `;`'s out in PS ^^ (except to have multiple statements on the same line) - I'll edit your post if I can - done, also added a missing double-quote at the end of the message body*

I've tried to simplify as much as I could.

Can you please try to run this with appropriate values in config, and see if the results give you the correct stuck transactions count for each customer ?

I'll try to improve as needed.

**EDIT :** maybe what is slowing you down is the mail sending step :) leave it commented out during the first tests

```
#config
$mainFolder = "C:\Application\Customer."
$tenantID = 0 # test value
$maxTenantID = 2 # test value
$registerPath = "oneDirectory"

#initialize results array
$results = @()

#iterate through customers
while($tenantID -le $maxTenantID) {

    #build Path
    $loc = Join-Path $mainFolder$tenantID $registerPath

    #list files (excluding .ini)
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $loc -Recurse -Exclude "*.ini" |
        Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }

    #reset counter
    $stuckCount = 0

    #iterate through files    
    foreach($file in $files) {

        #split path to get parent and ancestor        
        $parent = Split-Path $file.Directory -Leaf
        $ancestor = Split-Path $file.Directory.Parent.Parent -Leaf

        #if ancestor is oneDirectory and parent is transactions
        if(($ancestor -eq "oneDirectory") -and ($parent -eq "transactions")) {

            #increment counter
            $stuckCount++
        }
    }

    #create a custom object with customer name and stuck transactions count, and add it to the results array
    $results += [PSCustomObject]@{ Customer = $tenantID ; StuckCount = $stuckCount }

    if($stuckCount -gt 50) {
        #uncomment to send a mail if stuck transation count is over 50 for this customer
        #Send-MailMessage -From "email@whatever.com" -To "email@whatever.com" -SmtpServer "smtp.whatever.com" -Subject "Transactions stuck" -Body "$loc has over 50 transactions."
    }

    #increment customer ID
    $tenantID++
}

#output results array
$results

#example output :
#Customer StuckCount
#-------- -----------
#       0          58
#       1         110
#       2          13

#you could also send a global mail report here using $results array, for example :
#
#$results | ? { $_.StuckCount -gt 50 }
#
#will only list the customers with a stuck transaction count over 50
```